# Can I make this shape as one solid object with css only?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have the desired shape but I am unable to get the `box-shadow` due to the use of css triangles.

(I don't want to use `filter: drop-shadow` unless that is the only option)

Here is what I currently have:

```
.serTabs li:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #5b5b5b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  left: 5px;
}

.serTabs li:after {
  border-left: 10px solid #5b5b5b;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  left: 10px;
}
```

fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/zNCQ8/)

Is there any shape or workaround that I can make this as one solid object not a before and after?

(I'm talking about the little bullet point on the left side)

Comment: No, but I invite anyone to prove me wrong because that would be amazing.

Comment: I'm still trying other options and I think I might actually find a way to do this!!

Comment: for me this is an icon, and in this case I'd use an iconfont, like http://fontawesome.io/icon/map-marker and rotate it.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from but I am a css junkie and if I can do it in css, then I shall :p.

Comment: @TreeTree I found a way to make that shape with a single object only!!

Comment: @JoshPowell I saw, that's quite good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow I was able to get pretty darn close using `border-radius` on a square.

(This is like 95% of the shape but to make it elongate over being perfectly square may be impossible.)

(Holy cahoots! It works great with a border, outline, box-shadow, and more! [WOW](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/rKUa4/1/))

Here is the css:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: brown;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 0 100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

Fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/rKUa4/)

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Haha sorry mate, if you want you can post it and I'll give you a +1 for the effort! I can't believe this is possible but I am very excited now that I know it is!

Comment: Messed around a bit... `skewY` seems to help.

Comment: I have been fiddling with `skewY` and I think I like the perfect circle the best.

Answer (score 1):

you might take some inspiration from this site

it has some awesome tricks for making a heart and a curved arrow as well

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

for e.g this makes a badge ribbon

```
#badge-ribbon {
 position: relative;
 background: red;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius:    50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius:         50px;
}

#badge-ribbon:before,
#badge-ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  top: 70px;
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-140deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-140deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-140deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(-140deg);
}

#badge-ribbon:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(140deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(140deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(140deg);
}
```

also this speech bubble might help

```
#speech-bubble {
   width: 120px; 
   height: 80px; 
   background: purple;
   position: absolute;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
   border-radius: 10px;
}
#speech-bubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid purple;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
   margin: 13px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Comment: I have been on that website tons of times :] I got a fiddle I am working on with almost the desired shape!

Comment: Refer to my answer, there may be a better option but this is darn close!

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a little `skewY()`... Seems to look pretty good.

```
.bullet {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0px 50% 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(15deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 black;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vsdc8/)**

Comment: Not bad, I would have to tweak it but I think it is possible!

Comment: yeah you can use skew and rotate it as needed I'd guess.